# duplicate div when enter is hit while the input element in the div is in focus

Tags: javascript

I need help with duplicating div when enter is hit while the input element in the div is in focus

so there is a div which has an input element in it. I need to duplicate this div and place it right below the existing div whenever enter is hit while the cursor is in the input element.

Solutions which don't use jquery will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: tried to do it with js but it doesn't work and is too messed up to put up here... any guidelines on how to approach this problem will be of great help... I'll then try the suggested approach and update this thread... I am kinda newb with this... I am trying here - http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/vC3jH/)**

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='div1'>
<input type='text' onkeyup='clone_element(event)' />
</div>
</div>

<script>
function clone_element(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if(charCode == 13){
 var cDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
        var clonedDiv = cDiv.cloneNode (true);
        clonedDiv.id = "";
        var container = document.getElementById ("container");
        container.appendChild(clonedDiv);
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a high level overview...

- Listen for `keypress` event on the `input` element, for `keyCode` of `13`.
- Use `cloneNode()` to clone the node.
- Use the most appropriate node insertion method, such as `appendChild()` to insert the cloned element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to clone the div. This is likely to be the solution Alex mentioned. I have added the code.

```
function cloning(divid) {
    var container = document.getElementById(divid);
    var clone = document.getElementById('div_0').cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id','div_'+document.getElementById(divid).getElementsByTagName('div').length);
    container.appendChild (clone);
}
```

call the above function when you hit enter.

```
<script language = "javascript">
function searchKeyPress(e)
    {
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
     if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
     if (e.keyCode == 13)
      {
        alert("Enter received");
        cloning('divid');
      }
    }   

</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="searchKeyPress()">
```